# Не обрабатывает событие

Tags: java, android

недавно начал изучать андроид,написал небольшую програму,для выбора цвета и его описания

```
public class ColorMy extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Spinner spinnerFarbeAuswahl;
    private TextView textViewfurColorbeschreibung;
    Button buttonFarbeAuswahl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_my);
        spinnerFarbeAuswahl = findViewById(R.id.spinnerColorAuswahl);
        textViewfurColorbeschreibung = findViewById(R.id.textViewFurBeschreibung);
        buttonFarbeAuswahl = findViewById(R.id.buttonFarbeAuswahl);
    }

    View.OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = spinnerFarbeAuswahl.getSelectedItemPosition();
        String description = getDescriptionByPosition(position);
        textViewfurColorbeschreibung.setText(description);

        }
    };


    private String getDescriptionByPosition(int position){
        String [] descriptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorbeschreibung);
        return descriptions[position];
    }
}
```

теперь по идеи надо написать только 
 buttonFarbeAuswahl.setOnClickListener(oclBtn);
чтобы кнопка обрабатывала событие и выводила на экран текст,но 
buttonFarbeAuswahl не могу написать,и не погу понять почему

быд бы рад,если бы обьяснили почему

Comment: Откуда ж нам знать, почему вы не можете написать

Comment: Наверное потому что пишите не туда - нужно внутри метода, например, в `onCreate` последней строкой. И переменная, которой вы присвоили слушатель у вас `oclBtnOk`, а не `oclBtn`

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_my);
    spinnerFarbeAuswahl = findViewById(R.id.spinnerColorAuswahl);
    textViewfurColorbeschreibung = findViewById(R.id.textViewFurBeschreibung);
    buttonFarbeAuswahl = findViewById(R.id.buttonFarbeAuswahl);

    buttonFarbeAuswahl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       int position = spinnerFarbeAuswahl.getSelectedItemPosition();
       String description = getDescriptionByPosition(position);
       textViewfurColorbeschreibung.setText(description);
     }
   }); 
}
```